# Laravel slugs in routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm hoping this turns out to be a simple situation that I have just overlooked in the documentation. I am refactoring our web application to utilize slugs in urls. Our company allows many organizations to register, each having their own page and sub pages. I am trying to accomplish something like the below:

```
Route::get('/{organization-slug}', 'OrganizationController@index');
Route::get('/{organization-slug}/{organization-subpage-slug}', 'OrganizationController@subpage');
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

However, how can I do this without conflicting with other routes? For example if I have `'/{organization-slug}'` this would also match for any root level route. So if a user goes to `/dashboard`, they would be routed to `OrganizationController@index` instead of `DashboardController@index`

Does laravel have built in functionality to handle this situation?

**EDIT**

In response to some of the answers stating that the order of the routes file is what needs to be revised. I have created a new laravel project to test this, and added the following routes to `/routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/{some_id}', function($some_id){
    echo $some_id;
});
Route::get('/{some_id}/{another_id}', function($some_id, $another_id){
    echo $some_id . ' - ' . $another_id;
});
Route::get('/hardcoded/subhard', function(){
    echo 'This is the value returned from hardcoded url with sub directory';
});
Route::get('/hardcoded', function(){
    echo 'This is the value returned from hardcoded url';
});
```

The routes `/hardcoded/subhard` and `/hardcoded` are never reached. When this order is used. However, if we move the static routes above the dynamic like below:

```
Route::get('/hardcoded/subhard', function(){
    echo 'This is the value returned from hardcoded url with sub directory';
});
Route::get('/hardcoded', function(){
    echo 'This is the value returned from hardcoded url';
});
Route::get('/{some_id}', function($some_id){
    echo $some_id;
});
Route::get('/{some_id}/{another_id}', function($some_id, $another_id){
    echo $some_id . ' - ' . $another_id;
});
```

Then the appropriate routes appear to be working as expected. Is this correct?

Comment: can you change your dashboard url to `/user/dashboard/` ?

Comment: I'm mainly using that route as an example as there are many more routes at the root level like that one

Comment: Have you tried to prepend the organization routes with something like 'orgs' (in a group) then other routes.. I feel this might be more stable and less bug proned. If this is not an option you can disregard this comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order is important in route file.
Put the most generic in last.

---

Edited:

> `Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
>   Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
>   Route::get('/{organization-slug}/{organization-subpage-slug}', 'OrganizationController@subpage');
>   Route::get('/{organization-slug}', 'OrganizationController@index');`

Comment: This does not appear to make a difference. I have updated my question with a test I did in a clean laravel install. Please see details.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel considers the last route definition for the same resource as the valid route. So just put the `Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');` after the definition of the route of slugs:

```
Route::get('/{organization-slug}', 'OrganizationController@index');
Route::get('/{organization-slug}/{organization-subpage-slug}', 'OrganizationController@subpage');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
```

Comment: Is that really working because i have tried but it didn't work

Comment: @AjayDeepakKumar. Answer unaccepted as you are correct. This is not working. The variable route appears to always be used regardless of order.

Comment: @JeanMarcos I have revised my question to include simple test routes testing this. Please see details.

Comment: as i can see @ThomasRift answer is working perfect as you looked for but if a slug is `dashboard` then it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Put `Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');` to the top in the route file :

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::get('/{organization-slug}', 'OrganizationController@index');
Route::get('/{organization-slug}/{organization-subpage-slug}', 'OrganizationController@subpage');
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) for your routes.

Add `->where('organization-slug', '^(?!.*dashboard).*$')` at the end of your parameterized routes, and they will work for any slugs except 'dashboard', and dashboard route also will work safely for `http://yourdomain.com/dashboard`.

```
Route::get('/{organization-slug}', 'OrganizationController@index')->where('organization-slug', '^(?!.*dashboard).*$');
Route::get('/{organization-slug}/{organization-subpage-slug}', 'OrganizationController@subpage')->where('organization-slug', '^(?!.*dashboard).*$');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
```

And if you have other routes like dashboard you can add them as well.

```
Route::get('/{organization-slug}', 'OrganizationController@index')->where('organization-slug', '^(?!.*dashboard|.*dashboard1|.*dashboard2|.*dashboard3).*$');
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. Since we have many routes and would have to write rules like this for a good percentage of them which include all other routes, we are trying to stay away from this. However if no other solution presents itself...this might be the "route" we have to take ;)